# Memory issue with ARC and storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I have a memory issue with an iPad app I am working on : 
it has only 3 views controllers, and a navigation controller. 
I swap view controllers from A to B with a push segue , then to C with a push segue, then to A again with a popToRootViewController instruction.

I have implemented didReceiveMemoryWarning on all the view controllers, just to know what happen : 
view B is correctly unload from memory but view C seems to duplicate itself and consumes memory ! 
When I trig a memory warning, I can see severals view C answering...

It don't look like circular retain because I declared all my parents reference as weak, and because the leak instruments doesn't detect any leaks, nor retain cycles, but memory increase.
and this cause crash when testing with a real iPad.

what can I do ? where can I look at ? 
Is it possible to ask the navigation controllers to release all its previous object but the current on-screen one ?

edit :

in view didload, I have added some observers as below :

```
 NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidUndo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification object:undoManager];
[dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidRedo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification object:undoManager];
```

is it possible that doing this make that dnc keeps a retain reference to self somewhere ?

Comment: What part of the code could be useful ?

Comment: Were your views are alloc/inited, where the "swapping" happens, your didReceiveMemoryWarning, etc.

Comment: I chose to use storyboard for everything, in order not to care allocating / deallocating the view.
To swap view, I simple trig a "push" segue on my navigation controller, the only manual operation I do is to call :  
  
    `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` 
  
to go back to the first view.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  I forgot you were using StoryBoards.  Your best bet is to use the Leaks tool or the Alloc tool in instruments and see what objects are being created and living the most.

Comment: I am seeing that nearly all the IBoutlet objects stay loaded. 
Should I nil all of them before popToRootViewControllerAnimated ?
Is there a way to know which one retain my view ? 

and I have also a lot of gesture recognizer that I have manually added on my view. Should I remove them as well ?

Comment: You don't have to nil them if you are using ARC.  ARC should automatically release them once there is no longer a strong pointer to them.  I don't know of a way to see which one is retaining it.  There probably is but I have looked and can't find a way.   You should remove all GestureRecognizers and anything else so that it will dealloc.

Comment: I think I found the issue : I was loading a external component that retained its delegate ! 
I found it by looking at all the lines in the alloc tool like you said. Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Can you mark mine as answer so I can get some credit for help with instruments? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to nil them if you are using ARC. ARC should automatically release them once there is no longer a strong pointer to them. I don't know of a way to see which one is retaining it. There probably is but I have looked and can't find a way. You should remove all GestureRecognizers and anything else so that it will dealloc.

Comment: super ! 
the dealloc method is firing now.